# How to get all files from a folder in sharepoint?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint-2010

I am working on share point application. I want to get all files from a sub folder which is in a library.Library name is "Record Library". Inside this library folder name is "PROCUREMENT". Inside this folder i have one more folder name is "PURCHASING". In this folder i have file. I want to get all those file names. How can i get?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/sharepoint-2010-how-to-get-all-items-in-a-folder-contained-in-a-list

This might help. People will not write the code for you. You need to attempt what you are asking.